# How to register my ApplicationContextProvider Service in Spring boot Application?

Tags: spring-boot, javabeans, applicationcontext

I need to create a Bean object dynamically.

This is my BeanUtil

```
@Service
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }
}
```

unfortunately, the context is null
How to call setApplicationContext function before Bean creating process

Usage:

```
@Service
public class MainService {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataConsumer.class);

    public final static TheWorker worker = new TheWorker(ApplicationContextProvider .getBean(TheService.class));
    ...
```

My application startup:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"path.to.endpoints", "path.to.services", "path.to.workers", "path.to.utils"})
public class TheApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TheApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: can you elaborate your requirement more? what do you mean by creating bean dynamically?

Comment: Don't please don't. This should be considered to be a hack rather than a proper solution. The solution is use dependency injection.